# Php, in_array, 0 value

Tags: php, arrays

I was trying to understand the `in_array` behavior at the next scenario:

```
$arr = array(2 => 'Bye', 52, 77, 3 => 'Hey');
var_dump(in_array(0, $arr));
```

The returned value of the `in_array()` is boolean `true`. As you can see there is **no** value equal to `0`, so if can some one please help me understand why does the function return true?

Comment: I see two entries equal to 0 in this array

Comment: Hey Jonathan, Thank you for your answer realy good one, thanks again and have a nice day.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is a known issue, per the comments in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Consider the following examples:

```
in_array(0, array(42));      // FALSE
in_array(0, array('42'));    // FALSE
in_array(0, array('Foo'));   // TRUE
```

To avoid this, provide the third paramter, `true`, placing the comparison in *strict mode* which will not only compare values, but types as well:

```
var_dump(in_array(0, $arr, true));
```

Other work-arounds exist that don't necessitate every check being placed in strict-mode:

```
in_array($value, $my_array, empty($value) && $value !== '0');
```

#### But Why?

The reason behind all of this is likely [string-to-number conversions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). If we attempt to get a number from "Bye", we are given `0`, which is the value we're asking to look-up.

```
echo intval("Bye"); // 0
```

To confirm this, we can use `array_search` to find the key that is associated with the *matching* value:

```
$arr = array(2 => 'Bye', 52, 77, 3 => 'Hey');
echo array_search(0, $arr);
```

In this, the returned key is `2`, meaning `0` is being found in the conversion of `Bye` to an integer.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained why PHP evaluates `0 == 'string'` to TRUE

Comment: Yeah, I just wasn't sure why either . . . I posted my experiments/conclusions in my answer, as well as the specific line about strings being converted to 0, but thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @ernie Nice work. I figured the natural thing would be to leverage `array_search` to see which value PHP is finding to be equal to `0`, and sure enough it's the first string that doesn't start with an number in it.

Comment: Definitely a fun little question - didn't realize that strings were generally converted to 0 during type juggling, and that loose string/number comparisons would default to numeric comparisons.

Comment: @ernie A string of '4u' would be converted to 4 after juggling. But if the first character is not a number, it will be converted to 0 instead. Definitely a fun question.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding a third parameter `true` (strict mode) to your `in_array` call.

Answer (score 4):

This is a result of the loose comparison and [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Loose comparison means that PHP is using `==` not `===` when comparing elements.  `==` does not compare that the two variable types are equal, only their value, while `===` will ensure that they match in type and value (e.g. compare `0 == FALSE` and `0 === FALSE`).

So, basically, your in_array function is checking:

```
0 == 'Bye'
0 == 'Hey'
0 == 77
```

*Note that the 52 will get lost due to the way you created your array.*

So, note that if you do:

```
print (0 == 'Bye');
```

You will get 1.  Apparently, PHP is [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the 'Bye' to 0, which is the same thing that will happen when you cast a string to an int, e.g. `(int) 'string'` will equal 0.  Specific reference from [the String conversion to numbers doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) (Emphasis added):

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   **Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero)**. Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

Apparently, the integer type takes precedence over the string type (i.e. it could just as easily be doing the comparison by casting the int 0 to a string, which would then return False).  This is specified in the [comparison operators doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

Thanks for an interesting question that led me to do some research and learn something new!

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation. I just ran into the problem of this post and could not figure out _why_ PHP was doing what it is doing. Not sure how I am going to remember this as this feels really contrary to how PHP works. But having your full explanation gives my brain a fighting chance to 'vaguely recall' such errors. Thank you for taking the time to do the research to figure this all out!

Answer (score 1):

in_array is supposed to be used on indexed arrays ([0], [1], [2] etc), not with a dictionary as you have defined (key-value store).

If you want to check if your array $arr includes '0', try using the PHP function array_key_exists instead - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php.

```
var_dump(array_key_exists(0, $arr));
```

Comment: in_array has no limitation on whether the array is indexed or not; all it does is check if the values in the array (indexed or hashed) match the needle.

Answer (score 0):

Type compare (third parameter) needs more system resources and more time.
Simply do that:

```
$x=0;
$result=in_array($x.'',array('ABC','BAC','12c','54'));
var_dump($result);
```