# Php - in_array() and ! in_array() check 0 value

Tags: php, arrays

```
if(( (in_array(0,$status_arr)) || (in_array(0,$genstatus_arr)) ) && 
    ((!in_array(0,$escalation_arr)) || (!in_array(0,$genescalation_arr))) ){

     echo 'Something';

}else if(( (in_array(1,$status_arr)) || (in_array(1,$genstatus_arr)) )){

    echo 'Something Else';

}
```

Here I am comparing `0` value `in_array` and `non-zero` which is `!in_array`. The results varies according to if-else condition but does not output expected result.

To avoid this, I tried with the third parameter, `true`, placing the comparison in strict mode which will not only compare values, but types as well:

How can I check if `0` or `1` exists in some array and do not exist in another array ?

The array values would be like below:

```
var_dump($status_arr);
   array (size=6)
  0 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => string '0' (length=1)
  3 => string '0' (length=1)
  4 => string '0' (length=1)

var_dump($genstatus_arr);
   array (size=6)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
```

For the below condition its not working

```
if( (in_array(0,$status_arr)) && (!in_array(0,$genstatus_arr)) )
```

Also its not a possible duplicate of [IN ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846769/php-in-array-0-value)

Comment: edit with your print_r($arr)

Comment: "Results are abnormal" – what results do you get and what do you expect instead?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, array values updated.

Comment: the edit that you made is for which array? can you be more specific?

Comment: Abnormal here states, that if I expect `in_array` to check value `0` inside an array is not working. Also `!in_array`

Comment: Define "not working". Very simply: show us one array (`print_r`), show us a specific `in_array` piece of code, tell us what you expect the result to be, show us what the actual result is.

Comment: and your php version is ? this is my output bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true) I have php 5.5.9

Comment: OK, thanks, but again: **"not working" doesn't mean anything!** What do you *expect* and what do you *get*?

Comment: change the print_r(array) by var_dump(array)

Comment: `var_dump` gives `string '0'`

Comment: this if( (in_array(0,$status_arr)) && (!in_array(0,$genstatus_arr)) ) works as espected

Comment: OK, last try: do you expect `(in_array(0,$status_arr)) && (!in_array(0,$genstatus_arr))` to be `true` or `false`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var_dump(in_array(0, $status_arr, true));

Should return `true`, nothing abnormal there. If you are seeing `false` it is most probably because either of your `0`'s is a string `0` and not numeric `0`.

If that is the case, remove the `strict` parameter

```
$array=array(0,2,3);
var_dump(in_array(0,$array,true));
```

Returns

```
 bool(true)
```

And

```
$array=array('0','2','3');
var_dump(in_array(0,$array,true));
```

Returns

```
bool(false)
```

You mentioned

> For the below condition its not working

```
print_r($status_arr);
Array([0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0)

print_r($genstatus_arr);
Array([0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1)

if( (in_array(0,$status_arr)) && (!in_array(0,$genstatus_arr)) )
```

Which is an incorrect observation, because the condition works perfectly fine.

**[Example](https://eval.in/308192)**

Comment: `var_dump(in_array(0, $genstatus_arr, true));` outputs `boolean false`. Should I make it `in_array('0')`

Comment: Why do you want that last `true` parameter in there? Just remove it. That will match a `0` with a `0` but not a `0` with a `'0'` Since one is a number and other is a string.

Comment: `var_dump(in_array(0, $genstatus_arr));`

Answer (score 0):

In your case your are trying to work with strings

```
var_dump($status_arr);
   array (size=6)
  0 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => string '0' (length=1)
  3 => string '0' (length=1)
  4 => string '0' (length=1)

var_dump($genstatus_arr);
   array (size=6)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
```

Just try this example:

```
<?php

$status_arr = array();
$status_arr = array_pad($status_arr, 6, 0);

$genstatus_arr = array();
$genstatus_arr = array_pad($genstatus_arr, 6, 1);

var_dump($status_arr);
var_dump($genstatus_arr);

if( (in_array(0,$status_arr)) && (!in_array(0,$genstatus_arr)) )  {

     echo 'Works as espected';

}
```